# REST Updating field that has a looked up value from the database

Tags: json, rest, lookup, put

Take the following scenario:

I want to update a Manufacturer field on a car object via a REST PUT call.  The data that should be sent looks like this:

```
{
  "Id": "1000000251"
  "Manufacturer": "Honda"
}
```

The key here is that the Manufacturer field's value comes from a set list of choices stored in the database.  I also provide the client with a separate GET call that lets them retrieve the list of valid Manufacturers.  If the user provides the value "Honnnda", I will return a validation error.

In the database, I have the following choices to be looked up:

```
1 Honda
2 Toyota
3 Ford
```

Is it preferred to force them to know our internal unique Id's for each of them (safer), and thus including a ManufacturerId field on my JSON object, or can I allow them to update the field via the text value?  I'll validate the input in both scenarios.  Also, before sending the PUT request, they will be required to get the list of available manufacterers regardless.

EDIT - The users will need to get a list of the available manufacturers before making the PUT call because they'll need to know ahead of time what are the valid choices they can make.  I used car as a "more tangible" example, but my system does not actually deal with cars.

Comment: Be aware that HTTP does not allow you to update just a single property of a larger representation with PUT. You must update the entire representation.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely ok.  I just used an abridged version of the object for brevity to isolate my quesiton.  That doesn't affect what I'm asking. :)

Comment: Well, as long as you can control your api-side code, it really does not matter. However, as a user, its more convenient to send "Honda" than "42" I guess... Can you elaborate on why users will need to GET a list of "available manufacterers regardless"?

Comment: Yes, I will update the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST doesn't really say much about this subject.
However, generally REST does prefer that you use URIs as idenitifiers, so one could argue that you should send..

```
{
  "Id": "1000000251"
  "Manufacturer": "http://myapi.com/manufacturers/1"
}
```

I'm not convinced it is necessary though.  There is a segment of the REST community that argue using identifiers in a representation makes the representation not `self-descriptive` because what that identifier means could change between the time the user-agent got the identifier and when it used it.  Personally, I don't buy that either.

I would say, don't sweat it.  Do whatever works best for your scenario.

Comment: I appreciate this answer.  I'd prefer not to provide to the outside clients our internal id's (not because of security, but because they really make no sense).  I'm thinking it would be more user friendly to the client to allow them to specify the text value that they want to use and then I'll just validate it and possibly send back a 400 error if they provide bad data.  Then, worse-case scenario, they could re-lookup the valid choices for Manufacturer.

Comment: @AdamLevitt  That seems perfectly reasonable to me.